# How do I store a variable in Python

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to make this code ask a maths question and tell the user that if the answer is correct it should add a point and store the points to get them a result out of 10 but if they get it wrong it should tell them the right answer and move on to the next question and don't know how to code that

```
number = 0
number = int(raw_input ("hello, please enter a times table you would like to practice "))    
while number > 12 or number < 2: 
    if number > 12:
        print "number is too big must be between 2 and 12 "
    else:
        print "number is too small must be between 2 and 12 "
    number = int(raw_input("please enter a number between 2 and 12: "))

import random
for i in range (11) :
    num_1 = random.randint(2, 12)
    right_answer = raw_input( str(i) + " what is " + str(number) + " times " + str(num_1))
```

**this is what am trying to recreate**

Welcome to the times table tester

what table would you like to practice? 17

sorry, thats too big. The number be between 2 and 12.

what table would you like to practice? 0

sorry, thats too small. The number be between 2 and 12

what table would you like to practice? 4

1 What is 4 times 7? 28  correct

2 what is 4 times 6? 24 correct

3 what is 4 times 9? 36 correct

4 what is 4 times 2? 8 correct

5 what is 4 time 5? 20 correct

6 what is 4 times 3? 43  incorrect 4 * 3 = 12

7 what is 4 times 4? 44  incorrect 4 * 4 = 16

8 what is 4 times 6? 46  incorrect 4 * 6 = 24

9 what is 4 times 9? 49  incorrect 4 * 9 = 36

10 what is 4 times 5? 45 incorrect 4 * 5 = 20

you scored 5 out of 10

goodbye and thanks for playing

Comment: Please clarify your question, youre mentioning various requirements. What is the exact part you don't understand (the way to store a variable ??, e.g. variableName = 42)

Comment: well the code on the last line asks the user a question from the chosen number above, say like the program asks you 5x3 you say 15 how do i make it tell the user that it either right or wrong and move to the next question and so on till it adds up all the right answers out of 10

Comment: You check if the answer was right or wrong, and then you move to the next question if it was right, or you ask again if it was wrong. Or in other words "Just do it!".

Comment: Note that `for i in range(11)` gives you 11 iterations, not 10

Comment: i'll will start a new question and show you what i am trying to recreate, scratch that i have to wait 7days before i can post another question as someone down voted this question...thanks

Comment: You don't need to ask a new question. The point of downvoting is to encourage you to improve *this* question. If you do so, you will get upvotes.

Comment: fine, all type out what am trying to make after the code as because i dont have enough rep to post images

Comment: You can modify this question instead, but that will make the existing answers invalid. But I guess that's not a big problem. However, most likely you have to wait a week, yes. You should have read about how to ask a good question first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple way to do this :

```
import random

score = 0
number = int(raw_input ('hello, please enter a times table you would like to practice \n'))    
while number > 12 or number < 2: 
    if number > 12:
        print 'number is too big must be between 2 and 12 \n'
    else:
        print 'number is too small must be between 2 and 12 \n'
    number = int(raw_input('please enter a number between 2 and 12: \n'))

for i in range (11):

    num_1 = random.randint(2, 12)
    answer = int(raw_input('%s what is %s times %s ?\n)'%(i,number,num_1)))

    if answer == number*num_1:
        print 'Right answer!'
        score += 1
    else:
        print 'Wrong answer!\nThe correct answer was %s'%(number*num_1)

print 'You made a score of %s'%score
```

Comment: by any chance is this possible without the %s's and /n's and the % signs?

Comment: or is different format of those symbols please and thank you, you've made my day :)

Comment: Yes of course , as you did in your first script.
\n is for adding a line feed
%s is for substitution as string and %thing is to set thing as substitution element.
So just use your first prints as they are.

Comment: so i can replace the %s's and %'s with str()

Comment: Yes , for example here the two prints give the same output


a = "foo"
b = "bar"
c = 5

print "a=%s b=%s c=%s"%(a,b,c)
print "a="+str(a)+" b="+str(b)+" c="+str(c)

Answer (score 0):

This stores the number 5 in the variable `points`:

```
points = 5
```

Or well, technically it creates (or fetches if already existing) an integer object with the value 5 and attaches the label `points` to it. But this is the closest to storing a value in a variables that you get in Python. Python doesn't have variables in the same sense that C has them for example. This can be confusing if your textbook assumes C-type  variable handling.

Comment: That question is to big/fuzzy to be possible to answer in a generic way. You need to make a more specific question. And post it as a new question, as this one now is answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get Number from user. Check enter string is number of not, in between 2 and 12, if not tell user to enter again.
2. Define variables which required during process. Used `Counter` to count correct and invalid answers.
3. Ask question to user and get answer from user.
4. Check given answer is correct or not.
5. Update `Counter` values according to answer.
6. Print Result.

Code:

```
print "Welcome to the times table tester."
#- Get Number from User.
while 1:
    try:
        number = int(raw_input ("What table would you like to practice?:"))
    except:
        print "You enter wrong string number. Only digits. Try again."
        continue

    if number>12:
        print "number is too big must be between 2 and 12 "
    elif number<2:
        print "number is too small must be between 2 and 12 "
    else:
        break

#- Define lib and variables.
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter() 
import random
total_que =  10
tmp = "\n%s:What is %s times %s:"
tmp1 = "Incorrect.%s * %s = %s"

#-start Questions.
for i in xrange (1, total_que+1) :
    num_1 = random.randint(2, 12)
    answer_u = raw_input(tmp%(i, number, num_1))
    answer_a = number*num_1
    try:
        answer_u = int(answer_u)
    except:
        cnt["Incorrect"] += 1
        print tmp1%(number, num_1, answer_a)
        continue

    if answer_u==answer_a:
        cnt["correct"] += 1
        print "Correct"
    else:
        cnt["Incorrect"] += 1
        print tmp1%(number, num_1, answer_a)

#- Result.
print "=========Result:======"
print "You scored %s out of %s \ngoodbye and thanks for playing."%(cnt["correct"], total_que)
```

Output:

```
python test.py 
Welcome to the times table tester.
What table would you like to practice?:ww
You enter wrong string number. Only digits. Try again.
What table would you like to practice?:100
number is too big must be between 2 and 12 
What table would you like to practice?:1
number is too small must be between 2 and 12 
What table would you like to practice?:3

1:What is 3 times 6:18
Correct

2:What is 3 times 4:12
Correct

3:What is 3 times 5:15
Correct

4:What is 3 times 7:21
Correct

5:What is 3 times 9:27
Correct

6:What is 3 times 7:34
Incorrect.3 * 7 = 21

7:What is 3 times 12:123
Incorrect.3 * 12 = 36

8:What is 3 times 10:r
Incorrect.3 * 10 = 30

9:What is 3 times 12:36
Correct

10:What is 3 times 4:12
Correct
=========Result:======
You scored 7 out of 10 
goodbye and thanks for playing.
```

Answer (score 0):

This program uses while-else loop for repetition until a number is found in between 2 and 12 and the logic of popping out an array element after it has been used.

```
import random
print "Welcome to the times table tester\n"
number = int(raw_input( "What table would you like to practice? "))

while (number > 12) or (number < 2):
    if number > 12 :
        print "\nSorry, thats too big. The number must be between 2 and 12"
        number = int(raw_input( "Enter some another number "))
    else :
        print "\nsorry, thats too small. The number must be between 2 and 12"
        number = int(raw_input( "Enter some another number "))
else:
    print "success"
    a=range(1,11)
    points = 0
    for i in range(1,11):
      rand_index = random.randint(0,len(a)-1)
      ans = int(raw_input("\n"+str(i)+": What is "+str(number)+" times "+str(a[rand_index])+"? "))
      if ans == number * a[rand_index]:
          print "Correct"
          a.pop(rand_index)
          points = points + 1
      else :
          print  "Incorrect "+str(number)+" * "+str(a[rand_index])+" = "+str(number*a[rand_index])
          a.pop(rand_index)
    print "You scored "+str(points)+" out of 10"
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the times table tester

What table would you like to practice? 15

Sorry, thats too big. The number must be between 2 and 12
Enter some another number 1

sorry, thats too small. The number must be between 2 and 12
Enter some another number 7
success

1: What is 7 times 2? 14
Correct

2: What is 7 times 9? 63
Correct

3: What is 7 times 6? 36
Incorrect 7 * 6 = 42

4: What is 7 times 5? 35
Correct

5: What is 7 times 3? 21
Correct

6: What is 7 times 4? 28
Correct

7: What is 7 times 7? 40
Incorrect 7 * 7 = 49

8: What is 7 times 8? 56
Correct

9: What is 7 times 1? 7
Correct

10: What is 7 times 10? 70
Correct
You scored 8 out of 10
```